# Populate PDF form with PHP

Tags: php, forms, pdf

I am seeking a way to use PHP to populate a PDF form with data. I found something similar here, http://www.setasign.de/products/pdf-php-solutions/setapdf-formfiller/demos/gui-demo/ , but there must be something open source. Does anyone happen to recall any other libraries that can perform this task of filling out a PDF form before outputting to the user? The key here is the form is existing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about FPDF :
http://www.phpclasses.org/package/421-PHP-Free-PDF-generation-class-without-PDFlib.html#download

Best,

Comment: Doesn't seem to support filling a PDF form. Not many of the classes out there do right now... I've only come across one at this point.